# How to save all plots of bokeh figure in svg and html, not only first one

Tags: python, html, svg, plot, bokeh

I am trying to save my bokeh figure in png, svg, and html formats. Figure consists of several lineplots, done in the loop. Svg and html files somehow contain only the first lineplot, although png and html outputs which open in the browser, show all the lineplots.

```
p = bokeh.plotting.figure(...)
colors = itertools.cycle(palette[10])
for i, color in zip(range(len(exp_labels)), colors):
       p.line(
       source=data.loc[data['experiment']==exp_labels[i]],
       x=x,
       y=y,
       color=color,
       legend=exp_labels[i]
       )   
bokeh.io.show(p) # figure in the browser shown fine
export_png(p, filename + '.png') # png export works fine
p.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(p, filename + '.svg') # svg  file shows only first lineplot
bokeh.io.save(p, filename + '.html') # html file also shows only first plot
```

If svg is unable to record in one file all the plots done in the loop, in spite of that they belong to the same figure `p`, I am wondering if its possible to somehow plot at once all the plots with `.groupby()`, since all the data belong to one dataframe, and solve this problem by such an approach.

**UPD**: Seems like the main problem is `svg`, and `html` has problems just because of the changed `output_backend`. If saved `html` first, it saved fine. However, it's still unclear how to save `svg` with all the lineplots, and how to switch `output_backend` to some default value. I couldn't find documentation for parameters of `output_backend`

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible there is just a bug. As of Bokeh 1.4, SVG support relies on a third party "canvas to SVG" library that is no longer maintained. It will need to be revisited from the ground up at some point, but that is a matter of resources. I would suggest you file a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)